# Magento 2 : Any Script or Extension to Attach Product Images to SKU

Tags: magento2, product, import, product-images, csv

I am looking a script or extension to do this:
I upload products via CSV, then run script or extension and attach product images (multiple) to the SKU, easy and fast and don't have to write in csv like a mule

I have 1000 products 10.000 images in this file path structure and products are in Magento 2 but without images attached to product

**/(SKU)/*.jpg** (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).jpg

example:**/coffeecup/1.jpg**, **coffeecup/2.jpg**, **etc**

this extension is for Magento 1, but i need any like this for Magento 2: https://marketplace.magento.com/nanowebgroup-nanowebgroup-imageimporter.html

Comment: Can this one help you? https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-import-all-products-with-images-magento-2.html

Comment: I was looking anything like a script that programatically attach image to product SKU automatically